# Convert DOCX to XML file

Tags: java, xml, docx

I need to use docx and xml files for translation prozess, not all of the translation tools can read xml, but docx, thats why i, xml because it can be better assigned to each other, i want to convert plain text from docx to xml and backwards(from xml to docx), with what can i begin , do you know if there is a way to do it programmatically using java? is it with dom4j possible?

Comment: DOCX *is* XML - a zip-compressed package of XML files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at [docx4j](http://www.docx4java.org/trac/docx4j) The site says:

> docx4j is a Java library for creating and manipulating Microsoft Open
>   XML (Word docx, Powerpoint pptx, and Excel xlsx) files.

Or, [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/). The site says:

> The Apache POI Project's mission is to create and maintain Java APIs
>   for manipulating various file formats based upon the Office Open XML
>   standards (OOXML) and Microsoft's OLE 2 Compound Document format
>   (OLE2). In short, you can read and write MS Excel files using Java.

One of the two should suffice. Since you are only concerned with `docx`, go for the first. If there are multiple formats, go for the second.

Comment: Anytime. Always make it a habit to search StackOverflow for questions before posting. Most of the questions have already been answered. Saves you time and effort. =)